# JedisPool vs JedisPooled

Tags: java, redis, connection-pooling, jedis

Looking at the [Jedis Getting Started](https://github.com/redis/jedis), I understand it's better to use connection pools to be threadsafe. To do so, I would need a `JedisPool` and a `try-with-resources` statement like so:

```
try (Jedis jedis = pool.getResource()) {
  jedis.set("hello", "world");
}
```

But then there's `JedisPooled`, which is the same as `JedisPool` just without the `try-with-resources`.

```
JedisPooled jedis = new JedisPooled("localhost", 6379);
jedis.sadd("hellow", "world");
```

So the question is, is there any other difference between JedisPool/Pooled, and why should I prefer JedisPool over JedisPooled (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `JedisPool` you can do transactions, e.g., something like this:

```java
try (Jedis jedis = pool.getResource()) {
  Transaction t = jedis.multi();
  t.sadd("planets", "Venus");
  t.sadd("planets", "Mars");
  t.exec();
}
```

It doesn't seem like you can do anything similar with `JedisPooled`.

Probably, there's more to that, but that's what I've stumbled on by myself.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that each command in JedisPooled

```
JedisPooled jedis = new JedisPooled("localhost", 6379);
jedis.sadd("hellow", "world");//fetch and release the resource
jedis.sadd("hellow", "what");//fetch and release the resource
```

will get the resource from the pool and release the resource into the pool without having to do try-with-resources.
JedisPool needs explicit try-with-resources

```
JedisPool pool = new JedisPool("localhost", 6379);
try (Jedis jedis = pool.getResource()) {
    jedis.set("foo", "bar"); // jedis resource is used
    System.out.println(jedis.get("foo")); // same jedis resource is used
}//here resource is released
```

REF : https://redis.io/docs/clients/java/